# std::move() with different data types

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I have `boost::array<int,8> array1` and I have `std::vector<int> temp(8);` how do I perform `std::move()` from `boost::array` to `std::vector`, I want to avoid `memcpy()`.

Comment: What do you mean by "`std::move()` from `boost::array` to `std::vector`"? Do you just want to create a `std::vector` from the `boost::array`?

Comment: I don't know about `boost::array` but if it's anything like `std::array` it doesn't have move semantics. If you move, it will move the elements in `O(N)` but can't move the storage in `O(1)` like `std::vector` can.

Comment: Among the valid comments and answers here, you should still avoid `memcpy`.  Use `std::copy()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't just move the guts of the container into a `std::vector`.  `std::vector` doesn't provide a way to take ownership of a buffer.  You will have to copy/move the individual elements into the `std::vector`.

---

One thing you could do is move the individual elements into the vector using it's iterator constructor and [`std::make_move_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/make_move_iterator).  You won't see any benefit with an `int` but if the type is faster to move than it is to copy then you will.  That would look like

```
some_container foo;
// populate foo
std::vector<some_type> moved_into{std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(foo)),
                                  std::make_move_iterator(std::end(foo))};
```

Answer (score 5):

`boost::array` and `std::vector` are unrelated types in the sense that `std::vector` knows nothing about how to be built out of `boost::array`.

On the other hand you can make use of `std::move` with iterators:

```
boost::array<int, 8> a;
std::vector<int> v;
v.reserve(a.size());

std::move(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(v));
```

Answer (score 0):

You move something if it makes sense to move it.

`array` doesn't hold a dynamically allocated buffer, so there is nothing to "steal". `int` is not an object that makes sense to move, so again, you can't even move individual elements of the array.

In a nutshell, there is no meaning of moving an `array<int>`.